# Grouping two variables based on third variable bins in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My intension is to group two variables pairs falling within a third variable's bin interval. such as: [image]

So that I can fetch a XY pair for a particular bin range of third variable, e.g., bin of 25-50 [image]

For the same, I tried to sort the **"Z"** variable and accordingly **"X"** and **"Y"** variables, with
`Z, Y, X = zip(*sorted(zip(Z,Y,X)))`, that works perfectly.
Now, I have to bin the sorted **"Z"** variable in the interval of 25 such as `bins=[0,25,50,75,100,125,150,200, rest all]`, here rest all means all >200 whatever available!

And in the last, I want to call the **"X"** and **"Y"** pairs falling in a particular bins of **"Z"**.

(plz find the datafile on https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qWM39NheJuEqgTycHhARwBcULmkX4k6B/view?usp=sharing)

I tried a lot, but didn't work well. Any remarks from the community!
Thanks

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh now, hope my query is more clear with two screenshots, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try `pd.cut`

```py
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['Z'], bins=[0,25,50,75,100,125,150,200, np.inf])
res = df[df['bins'] == pd.Interval(25, 50)]
```

Comment: first thanks for your support.  Actually I am dealing with three different spatial data variable each having dimension of (216, 28, 62) in terms of (time, lat, lon). And for the same I am trying to implement the above discussed things via looping over each grid cell (lat * lon= 1726) along all 216 time steps. Does the use of pandas feature will be optimized way or should I look for other NumPy features!!

Comment: @HARSHBARDHANKUMAR Don't understand what's the *above discussed things* in  *I am trying to implement the above discussed things*

Comment: I mean about my query and your nice two line hacks!! That's all perfect and answered well my question. Just I extended my query further in above comment that's create a room for confusion.

Comment: @HARSHBARDHANKUMAR Don't understand what you want to do in your first comment. Since your question is solved and if you want to get help on your extended query, you can post it as a new question with input, expected output and how to get the expected output.